# Token must be defined! error

Tags: angularjs, angular

When my main.ts is to bootstrap app.ts, everything looks good.

main.ts

```
import {bootstrap}    from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {AppComponent} from 'app/app';
import {ROUTER_PROVIDERS,ROUTER_DIRECTIVES} from 'angular2/router';
import {PLATFORM_DIRECTIVES,provide} from 'angular2/core';


bootstrap(AppComponent,
  [ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
    provide(PLATFORM_DIRECTIVES, {useValue: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES], multi:true}),
  ]);
```

app.ts

```
import {Component,View} from 'angular2/core';
import {RouteConfig} from 'angular2/router';
import {PlayerManagement} from './partials/player-management';
import {Report} from './partials/report';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: 'app/appComponent.html',
})


@RouteConfig([
  {path:'/playerManagement', name: 'PlayerManagement', component: PlayerManagement},
  {path:'/report',        name: 'Report',       component: Report}
])


export class AppComponent { }
```

But when I try to change to bootstrap another ts , login.ts, it gives me the error

```
angular2.js:22823 EXCEPTION: Token must be defined!
execute @   main.ts:22
```

the code line is,

```
execute: function() {
  bootstrap(LoginComponent, [ROUTER_PROVIDERS, provide(PLATFORM_DIRECTIVES, {
    useValue: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
    multi: true
  })]);
}
```

I compare the login.ts to app.ts , but no clue yet...

login.ts

```
import {Component,View} from 'angular2/core';
import {RouteConfig, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES} from 'angular2/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'login',
  templateUrl: 'app/login.html',
})

/*
@RouteConfig([
  {path:'/app', name: 'AppComponent', component: AppComponent}
])
*/

export class LoginComponent { }
```

**Updated main.ts**

```
import {bootstrap}    from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {LoginComponent} from 'app/login';
import {ROUTER_PROVIDERS,ROUTER_DIRECTIVES} from 'angular2/router';
import {PLATFORM_DIRECTIVES,provide} from 'angular2/core';


bootstrap(LoginComponent,
  [ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
    provide(PLATFORM_DIRECTIVES, {useValue: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES], multi:true}),
  ]);
```

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="">
  <head>
    <base href="/">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>video-platform</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <script src="lib/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/traceur-runtime.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/system-csp-production.src.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/Reflect.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/angular2.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/Rx.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/router.dev.js"></script>

    <script>
      System.config({
        packages: {
          app: {
            format: 'register',
            defaultExtension: 'ts'
          }
        }
      });
      System.import('app/main')
        .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <login>Loading....</login>
    <my-app>Loading....</my-app>
  </body>
</html>
```

My folder structure is

```
src
-app
--app.ts
--appComponent.html
--login.html
--login.ts
--main.ts
```

**Strack trace updated.**

```
STACKTRACE:
BrowserDomAdapter.logError @ angular2.js:22823
ExceptionHandler.call @ angular2.js:1165
(anonymous function) @ angular2.js:12624
run @ angular2-polyfills.js:138
(anonymous function) @ angular2.js:13328
NgZone.run @ angular2.js:13290
ApplicationRef_.bootstrap @ angular2.js:12602
bootstrap @ angular2.js:24543
execute @ main.ts:22
ensureEvaluated @ system-csp-production.src.js:2678
execute @ system-csp-production.src.js:2796
doDynamicExecute @ system-csp-production.src.js:715
link @ system-csp-production.src.js:908
doLink @ system-csp-production.src.js:569
updateLinkSetOnLoad @ system-csp-production.src.js:617
(anonymous function) @ system-csp-production.src.js:430
run @ angular2-polyfills.js:138
zoneBoundFn @ angular2-polyfills.js:111
lib$es6$promise$$internal$$tryCatch @ angular2-polyfills.js:1511
lib$es6$promise$$internal$$invokeCallback @ angular2-polyfills.js:1523
lib$es6$promise$$internal$$publish @ angular2-polyfills.js:1494
(anonymous function) @ angular2-polyfills.js:243
run @ angular2-polyfills.js:138
zoneBoundFn @ angular2-polyfills.js:111
lib$es6$promise$asap$$flush @ angular2-polyfills.js:1305
```

I am using ts, but i have attached the js (main.js) here as well

```
System.register("app/main", ["angular2/platform/browser", "app/login", "angular2/router", "angular2/core"], function($__export) {
  "use strict";
  var bootstrap,
      LoginComponent,
      ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
      ROUTER_DIRECTIVES,
      PLATFORM_DIRECTIVES,
      provide;
  return {
    setters: [function($__m) {
      bootstrap = $__m.bootstrap;
    }, function($__m) {
      LoginComponent = $__m.LoginComponent;
    }, function($__m) {
      ROUTER_PROVIDERS = $__m.ROUTER_PROVIDERS;
      ROUTER_DIRECTIVES = $__m.ROUTER_DIRECTIVES;
    }, function($__m) {
      PLATFORM_DIRECTIVES = $__m.PLATFORM_DIRECTIVES;
      provide = $__m.provide;
    }],
    execute: function() {
      bootstrap(LoginComponent, [ROUTER_PROVIDERS, provide(PLATFORM_DIRECTIVES, {
        useValue: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
        multi: true
      })]);
    }
  };
});
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "video-platform",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "gulp",
    "start": "gulp dev"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "angular2": "2.0.0-beta.2",
    "traceur": "0.0.102",
    "es6-promise": "^3.0.2",
    "es6-shim": "^0.33.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.0",
    "zone.js": "0.5.10",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.2",
    "systemjs": "0.19.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "3.9.0",
    "gulp-rename": "1.2.2",
    "gulp-traceur": "0.17.2",
    "gulp-webserver": "0.9.1",
    "gulp-print":"*"
  }
}
```

gulpfile.js

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    rename = require('gulp-rename'),
    traceur = require('gulp-traceur'),
    webserver = require('gulp-webserver');

// run init tasks
gulp.task('default', ['dependencies', 'ts','html', 'css']);

// run development task
gulp.task('dev', ['watch', 'serve']);

// serve the build dir
gulp.task('serve', function () {
  gulp.src('build')
    .pipe(webserver({
      open: true
    }));
});

// watch for changes and run the relevant task
gulp.task('watch', function () {
  //gulp.watch('src/**/*.js', ['js']);
  gulp.watch('src/**/*.ts', ['ts']);
  gulp.watch('src/**/*.html', ['html']);
  gulp.watch('src/**/*.css', ['css']);
});

// move dependencies into build dir
gulp.task('dependencies', function () {
  return gulp.src([
    'node_modules/traceur/bin/traceur-runtime.js',
    'node_modules/systemjs/dist/system-csp-production.src.js',
    'node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.js',
    'node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js',
    'node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.js',
    'node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js',
    'node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js',
    'node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js',
    'node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.map',
    'node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js',
    'node_modules/angular2/bundles/router.dev.js'
  ])
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build/lib'));
});




// transpile & move js
gulp.task('js', function () {
  return gulp.src('src/**/*.js')
    .pipe(rename({
      extname: ''
    }))
    .pipe(traceur({
      modules: 'instantiate',
      moduleName: true,
      annotations: true,
      types: true,
      memberVariables: true
    }))
    .pipe(rename({
      extname: '.js'
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build'));
});

// transpile & move ts
gulp.task('ts', function () {
  return gulp.src('src/**/*.ts')
    .pipe(rename({
      extname: ''
    }))
    .pipe(traceur({
      modules: 'instantiate',
      moduleName: true,
      annotations: true,
      types: true,
      memberVariables: true
    }))
    .pipe(rename({
      extname: '.ts'
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build'));
});

// move html
gulp.task('html', function () {
  return gulp.src('src/**/*.html')
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build'))
});

// move css
gulp.task('css', function () {
  return gulp.src('src/**/*.css')
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build'))
});
```

Comment: Could you provide the complete stacktrace of your error? Thanks!

Comment: updated Thierry. Thanks

Comment: Thanks! Which version of Angular2 do you use?

Comment: Sorry Thierry, rush to a meeting now. Will update here again... any known bug for earlier version?  Another work around i can try could be modify the app.ts's content with that of login.ts, while create another ts to hold the existing codes in the app.ts... but curious about the root cause..

Comment: angular2": "2.0.0-beta.2",

Comment: Thierry, strangely, after I change the selector from login to login-screen. It works. Then I change back to login, it also works.  Very interesting. Any thoughts?